# How to make an iframe run in the same page as what the bookmarklet was clicked on

Tags: javascript

```
(function() {
  let url = prompt("what site do you want to open?");
  let win = window.open(url, '_self');
  win.document.body.style.margin = '0';
  win.document.body.style.height = '100vh';
  var iframe = win.document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.style.border = 'none';
  iframe.style.width = '100%';
  iframe.style.height = '100%';
  iframe.style.margin = '0';
  iframe.src = url;

  win.document.body.appendChild(iframe);
})();
```

I have no idea what to do and I have researched a lok
here is my code, cant get it to wrok because it opens a new tab
you can edit it or redo it in any way you see fit

Comment: Have you tried removing this line `let win = window.open(url, '_self');`? And replacing `win` with `window`?

Comment: doesnt work at all when you do that

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me

```js
(function() {
  let url = prompt("what site do you want to open?");
  var iframe = window.document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.style.border = 'none';
  iframe.style.width = '100%';
  iframe.style.height = '100%';
  iframe.style.margin = '0';
  iframe.src = url;

  window.document.body.appendChild(iframe);
})();
```